# How do I convert a list of strings to a unicode value?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I receive the following:

```
value = ['\', 'n']
```

and my regular routine of converting to `unicode` and calling `ord` throws the error:

```
ord() expects a character, but string of length 2 found
```

It would seem that I need to join the characters within the list if `len(value) > 2`.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7291240/564538

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7291120/564538

Comment: Can you show us what "my regular routine" looks like? Because doing what you describe, `unicode(value)`, gives you an 11-character string, not 2. (Actually, it doesn't even get that far, because you'll get a `SyntaxError` from trying to enter that `value = ['\', 'n']` line…)

Comment: @PhillipCloud: I don't think it is. Presumably his "regular routine" is something like one of the answers to that problem, and his problem is something beyond that which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: In addition to showing us the code that doesn't work, please show us the actual contents of `value` (that is, copy and paste what you get if you `print` it), and the output you're hoping for.

Comment: You may want to read the Unicode HOWTO for Python [2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) or [3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) as appropriate. There are also a number of blog posts out there that try to make things clearer; I don't have a specific one to recommend, but Google turns up a bunch of options.

Comment: @abarnert You're right. I jumped the gun a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out how to treat this as a single string `'\\n'` that can then be interpreted as the single character `'\n'` according to some set of rules, like Python's unicode-escape rules, you have to decide exactly what you want before you can code it.

First, to turn a list of two single-character strings into one two-character string, just use `join`:

```
>>> value = ['\\', 'n']
>>> escaped_character = ''.join(value)
>>> escaped_character
'\\n'
```

Next, to interpret a two-character escape sequence as a single character, you have to know which escape rules you're trying to undo. If it's Python's Unicode escape, there's a codec named `unicode_escape` that does that:

```
>>> character = escaped_character.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> character
u'\n'
```

If, on the other hand, you're trying to undo UTF-8 encoding followed by Python string-escape, or C backslash escapes, or something different, you obviously have to write something different. And given what you've said about UTF-8, I think you probably do want something different. For example, `u'é'.encode('UTF-8')` is the two-byte sequence `'\xce\xa9'`. Just calling `decode('unicode_escape')` on that will give you the two-character sequence `u'\u00c3\u00a9'`, which is not what you want.

Anyway, now that you've got a single character, just call `ord`:

```
>>> char_ord = ord(character)
>>> char_ord
10
```

---

I'm not sure what the convert-to-unicode bit is about. If this is Python 3.x, the strings are already Unicode. If it's 2.x, and the strings are ASCII, it's guaranteed that `ord(s) == ord(unicode(s))`. If it's 2.x, and the strings are in some other encoding, just calling `unicode` on them is going to give you a `UnicodeError` or mojibake; you need to pass an encoding in as well, in which case you might as well use the `decode` method.

Comment: Sorry, my question probably isn't very clear (and my knowledge about encoding probably isn't bang on, either). My goal is to convert the character '\n' to its UTF-8 code point and from there convert it to binary/decimal.

Comment: @sdasdadas: First, where does the character `'\n'` come from in your example? Second, a single character can be 1-6 bytes in UTF-8, so "its UTF-8 code point" is meaningless. And if you have a UTF-8 string, and you want to get the numerical value of each byte, just call `ord` on each byte; no need to convert to a Unicode string unless you want to get the numerical values of the Unicode characters that the bytes decode to.

Comment: The character '\n' comes from a parser which returns the string `"\n"`. The code for `''.join(...)` solves what I initially meant to ask, so I thank you for that. I wanted to implement UTF-8 support within the parser and, for some reason, I foolishly assumed that the code points are padded with 0's. The term variable-width encoding makes a lot more sense to me now...

Comment: `''.join(['\\', '\n'])` doesn't give you the single-character string `'\n'`, it give you the two-character string `'\\n'`. If you want to parse that into `'\n'`, you need to do that explicitly (e.g., by using the `unicode_escape` quasi-codec… if that's the appropriate rule for your data).

Comment: @sdasdadas: Meanwhile, is the parser giving you a list of single-byte UTF-8 possibly-partial-character strings, or single-character possibly-multiple-byte UTF-8 strings, or…? Until you know what you have, you can't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this last comment. Your answer solved my issue (a while back) but to answer your question: the parser was giving me single-character multi-byte strings.