# Trouble converting UTF-8 string to XML/HTML string

Tags: python, html, character-encoding

I have a string that is encoded in UTF-8, and I am trying to display the text on a web page. I've noticed that any attempt I've made to convert any special characters to XML-encoded characters was a failure. I know what I'm doing wrong, but I don't know how to make it right.

> **Edit:** The original question only showed the following string as one without the `b` prefix, without paying any attention to the conversion with `str()`. Below is the updated conversion process that was not shown.

Here's the example string I'm working with, which has a horizontal ellipsis at the end:

```py
>>> html = b'<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\xe2\\x80\\xa6</p>'
>>> html = str(html)
```

My problem is that UTF-8 characters are of variable length, so I can't just do something like this:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\\(x[a-f\d]{2})', r'&#\1;', html) # Don't do this!
'<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&#xe2;&#x80;&#xa6;</p>'
```

This gives three extended characters that are totally valid UTF-8, but not the right encoding. In my case, I can simply do:

```py
>>> re.sub(r'\\xe2\\x80\\xa6', '&hellip;', html)
'<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&hellip;</p>'
```

But this only covers one of many character encodings. I obviously don't have the time, the patience, or any intention of writing substitutions for *every* character.

So, my question is this: how do I tell the byte-length of a character? Is there some byte mask I can use to tell if a byte is the first or last byte of a character? Any other method of determining the length, or a module that will do it for me, is welcome.

Comment: I'm using version 3.5

Comment: I receive them like this; it is not under my control.

Comment: Actually, that's not accurate. I receive it as a byte-prefixed string and convert it with `str()`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was making things more complicated for myself, wasn't I? Post this as an answer along with your link and I'll mark as accepted later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is being received as UTF8-encoded [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).  The bytes may be converted to a [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) by decoding them like this:

```
html = bytes_string.decode('utf-8')
```

or like this

```
html = str(bytes_string, 'utf-8')
```

Doing `str(bytes_string)` will not decode the bytes, it will return the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of the bytes.

Once decoded, characters can be converted to the equivalent html entities using data from the [html.entities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html) module in the standard library, and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
from html import entities                                                                                                                                                  

# If we don;t want to convert html tags, don't include
# '<' and '>' in the translation table.                                                                                                                                                                               
skip = {ord(x) for x in '<>'}                                                                                                                                              
trans_table = {k: '&{};'.format(v) 
               for k, v in entities.codepoint2name.items() if k not in skip}                                                                           

translated = s.translate(trans_table)                                                                                                                                      
print(translated)
```

Output

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&hellip;</p>
```

I discuss how the translation works in more depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50304817/5320906).